# php-cs-fixer: need more information on using fix --level option

Tags: php, symfony, coding-style, psr-2

Okay, I know `php-cs-fixer` allows following levels of fixes for coding standards:

```
php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/project --level=psr0
php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/project --level=psr1
php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/project --level=psr2
php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/project --level=symfony
```

I know that `psr0`, `psr1`, `psr2` levels maintain specified coding standards.

But I want to know what `--level=symfony` offers and how does that coding standard differ from `psr2`.

Also if we don't the provide the `--level` option at all. Does is assume `--level=psr2` by default?

Comment: I'd assume that `--level=symfony` would be a coding standard to use?

Comment: Yes I know that. But, I want to what additional things does it offer or how does it differ from PSR2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a good blog post](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/using-php-cs-fixer-to-fix-up-your-php-code#running-php-cs-fixer) on using `php-cs-fixer` and here it implies that by default it uses `psr2` fixers if the `--level` option is not provided.

But, if we pass `--level=symfony` explicitly it runs some *“additional” checks, which are targeted at Symfony and go above-and-beyond PSR2*

> By default, it runs “all PSR-2 fixers and some additional ones.” You
>   can toggle the level you want to run with the --level flag, which I’ll
>   be setting to psr2 so that the “additional” checks, which are targeted
>   at Symfony and go above-and-beyond PSR2, don’t throw me off. (It runs
>   the entire stack by default, which is called level “symfony” and
>   includes things like “Align equals signs in subsequent lines”).

Also the [php-cs-fixer README on github](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#usage) provides some information about the filters that are run in PSR-0, PSR-1, PSR-2 and symfony.

Answer (score 4):

Now in 2017, since version 2, **you can use `describe` command**.

```
vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer describe @PSR2
```

It shows you current fixers in the ruleset with names and description:

[image]

So for "Symfony" ruleset it would look like:

```
vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer describe @Symfony
```

And for single rule like:

```
vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer describe some_rule
```

#### Level changed to @Rule

Also notice `level` option was deprecated. Use it as rule, just with `@` prefix instead.

`vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer --rules=@PSR2`

If you look for more details, see [related PR](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/pull/2331).

Comment: If you could elaborate a little bit about this new command along with the link it would be more helpful.

Comment: I've added all info I could found + screenshot and description, what it does.

Answer (score 1):

As I see from this document https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/1.8/README.rst it executes this list of filters:

- blankline_after_open_tag - Ensure there is no code on the same line as the PHP open tag and it is followed by a blankline.
- concat_without_spaces - Concatenation should be used without spaces.
- double_arrow_multiline_whitespaces - Operator => should not be arounded by multi-line whitespaces.
- duplicate_semicolon - Remove duplicated semicolons.
- empty_return - A return statement wishing to return nothing should be simply "return".
- extra_empty_lines - Removes extra empty lines.
- include - Include and file path should be divided with a single space. File path should not be placed under brackets.
- join_function - Implode function should be used instead of join function.
- list_commas - Remove trailing commas in list function calls.
- multiline_array_trailing_comma - PHP multi-line arrays should have a trailing comma.
- namespace_no_leading_whitespace - The namespace declaration line shouldn't contain leading whitespace.
- new_with_braces - All instances created with new keyword must be followed by braces.
- no_blank_lines_after_class_opening - There should be no empty lines after class opening brace.
- no_empty_lines_after_phpdocs - There should not be blank lines between docblock and the documented element.
- object_operator - There should not be space before or after object T_OBJECT_OPERATOR.
- operators_spaces - Binary operators should be arounded by at least one space.
- phpdoc_indent - Docblocks should have the same indentation as the documented subject.
- phpdoc_no_access - @access annotations should be omitted from phpdocs.
- phpdoc_no_empty_return - @return void and @return null annotations should be omitted from phpdocs.
- phpdoc_no_package - @package and @subpackage annotations should be omitted from phpdocs.
- phpdoc_params - All items of the @param, @throws, @return, @var, and @type phpdoc tags must be aligned vertically.
- phpdoc_scalar - Scalar types should always be written in the same form. "int", not "integer"; "bool", not "boolean"; "float", not "real" or "double".
- phpdoc_separation - Annotations in phpdocs should be grouped together so that annotations of the same type immediately follow each other, and annotations of a different type are separated by a single blank line.
- phpdoc_short_description - Phpdocs short descriptions should end in either a full stop, exclamation mark, or question mark.
- phpdoc_to_comment - Docblocks should only be used on structural elements.
- phpdoc_trim - Phpdocs should start and end with content, excluding the very first and last line of the docblocks.
- phpdoc_type_to_var - @type should always be written as @var.
- phpdoc_var_without_name - @var and @type annotations should not contain the variable name.
- remove_leading_slash_use - Remove leading slashes in use clauses.
- remove_lines_between_uses - Removes line breaks between use statements.
- return - An empty line feed should precede a return statement.
- self_accessor - Inside a classy element "self" should be preferred to the class name itself.
- single_array_no_trailing_comma - PHP single-line arrays should not have trailing comma.
- single_blank_line_before_namespace - There should be exactly one blank line before a namespace declaration.
- single_quote - Convert double quotes to single quotes for simple strings.
- spaces_before_semicolon - Single-line whitespace before closing semicolon are
- spaces_cast - A single space should be between cast and variable.
- standardize_not_equal - Replace all <> with !=.
- ternary_spaces - Standardize spaces around ternary operator.
- trim_array_spaces - Arrays should be formatted like function/method arguments, without leading or trailing single line space.
- unalign_double_arrow - Unalign double arrow symbols.
- unalign_equals - Unalign equals symbols.
- unary_operators_spaces - Unary operators should be placed adjacent to their operands.
- unused_use - Unused use statements must be removed.
- whitespacy_lines - Remove trailing whitespace at the end of blank lines.